# Finding and replacing text in Intellij IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea

What do I have:

More then 100 lines of fields with same structure:

```
var type1Name:String = "<some text>";
var type2Name:String = "<some text>";
```

`<some text>` is always different. `name` is always same.

What I want:

Delete all `<some text>` in all fields. This is more likely to "find and replace" operation, to find something like `Name:String = "***";` and replace it with `Name:String = "";` in all cases.

How can i do this with **Intellij IDEA**?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

if it is in one file : <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>r</kbd> check the tick box `Regex` and look for `Name:String = \"[^\"]*\"` : this should match what you want.

Then replace it with whatever you want.

If it is in multiple file, use <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>r</kbd>