# How to undo in Intellij IDEA replace in files?

Tags: intellij-idea, search, replace, undo

In intellij 2022.1, I use `Ctrl+Shift+R` to bring up the *Replace in Files* window - it shows 100+ matches in 40+ files. The search string and the replace string differ in **only one character**, for example:  `this.bar.is.fooed` and `this.barf.is.fooed`. I only need to replace certain instances based on nearby text.

I'm in the groove, clicking the `Replace` button, checking the next entry, clicking, checking, ... and thinking my brain can keep things straight (it can't; neither can yours:-)  I'm halfway through when I realize the last few replaces were wrong.

How can I undo them? `Ctrl+Z` **is grayed out.** [This related SO question doesn't say](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28847575/finding-and-replacing-text-in-intellij-idea) and [neither does the JetBrains documentation!](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/finding-and-replacing-text-in-project.html#work_find_tool_window)

Comment: Use Local History to revert the changes: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/local-history.html. Undo/redo is not supported for Replace dialog, vote for the related request at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-265341.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I'm surprised I was the first vote on that one.

Comment: @CrazyCoder If you post your comment as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Local History](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/local-history.html) to revert the changes.

Undo/redo is not supported for Replace dialog, [vote for the related request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-265341).

Comment: How does it help to undo last changes in *multiple* files?

Answer (score 1):

For those not familiar with the "Show Local History" workflow:

1. Bring up the **Project Pane** and right-click on **the root of the project**.
2. In the right-click context menu, go to `Local History > Show Local History...`.
3. In the **History Pane**, select the edits you want to revert (if you mistakenly hit `Replace all`, then there will be an edit called `Replace all`).
4. Finally, right click on the edits you selected and select `Revert` from the context menu.